# I want to Put two arrays value in Map as key-Value

Tags: arrays, string, linkedhashmap

I want to Put two arrays value in LinkedHashMap as key-value.
Here is the snippet that I'm using:

```
        String[] s = answer.split("\\,");  
        String[] ss = aa.split("\\,");
        System.out.println(ss.length);  -->prints 3 
        System.out.println(s.length);   -->prints 3
```

What I want is to put s values as Key and ss values as Value in HashMap.

I'm trying to write code.

```
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            for(int j= 0;j<ss.length;j++){
                if(s[i].length()==s[j].length()){
                    testMap.put(s[i], ss[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

But unable to Put into Map. What I've done wrong?
And I'm using LinkedHashMap to preserve the order of Insertion.

Comment: I do not see where you are trying to perform addition in your code example... what are you trying to add?

Comment: What is the error or what are the values you have in your arrays?

Comment: Are you sure you want to add the same array elements as key- value pair. `testMap.put(s[i], s[j])` it will add `s[i]` element as key and value. What is the output you are getting and what you are unable to add?

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh corrected the code.

Comment: Here is output. And I know what is happening. It is putting last value of ss array in each keys. How to separate them?                                    Key = ID
Key = NAME
Key = VALUES
Values= ROMEO
Values= ROMEO
Values= ROMEO

Comment: post your `answer` and `aa` strings as well.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh  Output of aa String : 1 KLAXXON ROMEO and output is :Key = ID Key = NAME Key = VALUES Values= ROMEO Values= ROMEO Values= ROMEO

Comment: Assuming your Strings are `String answer="ID,NAME,VALUES";
  String aa="1,KLAXXON,ROMEO";` you are trying to map `ID` with `1` ,`NAME` with `KLAXXON` and `VALUES` with `ROMEO` ryt? if yes then why you are using two loops.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh Yes that is what I'm trying to do. And how can I do it? I know using two loops is not gonna help and it keeps adding the last value in each keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                testMap.put(s[i], ss[i]);
        }
```

I just have to change my loop condition to this. Instead of using two for loops. 
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, It will add accordingly

`String answer = "ID,NAME,VALUES";
        String aa = "1,KLAXXON,ROMEO";
        String[] s = answer.split("\\,");
        String[] ss = aa.split("\\,");`

`for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            testMap.put(s[i], ss[i]);
        }`

Output:
`{ID=1, NAME=KLAXXON, VALUES=ROMEO}`